# Speaker volume in Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, volume, microphone

Is there any way by which I can change the volume of the Speaker?

When I use Microphone class, I can set the mic.gain to set the gain in the microphone, likewise can I change the volume of the speaker?

I have seen, some websites allow you to change the decibel gain of the speaker in Flash. Can anyone help me understand this?

Thank You.

Comment: can you show a link to a website that does this?

Comment: perfect, thanks Joy. That site is definitely setting the volume of sounds played from flash, and not changing any settings of the actual speakers. So then the answer below from NeoRaptor should do it. However, you only get control of the sounds playing from the flash player. No way to make the speaker volume louder than the use setting, or to unmute it if the user uses their system mute.

Comment: But, can you tell me whether settings made by this app affect the local flash settings on the machine? The settings done on voxli.com has after effects on my application as well..

Comment: The site (voxli.com) is using a Shared Object (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) to store your volume preference. Notice that adjusting the volume on voxli does not change your system volume level, nor does it change the volume on other flash-based sites like youtube or vimeo. Its just the volume of that one flash movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change global sound values:

For AS2 change the sound volume of the _root:

```
var volumeChangeSound:Sound = new Sound(_root);
volumeChangeSound.setVolume(0); // goes from 0 to 100
```

For AS3:

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
var transform1:SoundTransform=new SoundTransform();
transform1.volume=0; // goes from 0 to 1
flash.media.SoundMixer.soundTransform=transform1;
```

[Sounds in as3: Tutorial: AS3 Basics – How to use library sounds in AS3 | 8bitrocket](http://www.8bitrocket.com/2008/05/23/tutorial-as3-basics-how-to-use-library-sounds-in-as3/#ixzz1VmrC4aq2)

Comment: Thank you so much. Just wanted to know, Will this work if I am using a Microphone and I receive some voice (in a voice chat)? Could the volume of this voice be controlled by the above method?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't played with the microphone. It has to... if not SoundMixer then whatever is used in code to generate that voice chat should be controlable in the same fashion.